# Magento : mobile/web themes

Tags: magento

first i have 2 themes mobile and theme.

i wanna know how to enable web theme if the customer connect from the web

else if he is connecting from mobile then enable the mobile theme.

is there any way to do that in the admin panel or by developpement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Configuration -> General -> Design.

Under Themes -> Template click **Add exeption**, fill **Matched Expression** with *iPhone|Android* and **Value** with *theme name*. Repeat same on **Skin (Images / CSS)**, **Layout**, **Default**.

It should look like https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2030135/mobile.jpeg